# UserAuthId property not set when mocking a user session in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to mock the user session in a BasicAppHost for testing as follows:

```
TestMode = true;
container.Register<IAuthSession>(c => new AuthUserSession
        {
                UserAuthId = "1",
                Language = "en",
                PhoneNumber = "*****",
                FirstName = "Test",
                LastName = "User",
                PrimaryEmail = "test@emailtest.com",
                UserAuthName    = "testuser",
                TimeZone = "America/Guatemala"

            }
        );
```

But when the session is retrieved from the Service the **UserAuthId** property is retrieved with empty value and the other values are retrieved correctly.

I'm retrieving the user session as follows:

```
var session = SessionAs<IAuthSession>();
```

Here you can see de values retrieved values:

[image]

I'm using service stack V4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce this behavior, which is working as expected in the example below:

```
public class MockSessionTest {}

public class MockSessionTestService : Service
{
    public object Any(MockSessionTest request) => 
       SessionAs<AuthUserSession>();
}

using (var appHost = new BasicAppHost
{
    ConfigureAppHost = host => host.RegisterService(typeof(MockSessionTestService)),
    ConfigureContainer = x => x.Register<IAuthSession>(c => new AuthUserSession {
        UserAuthId = "1",
        Language = "en",
        PhoneNumber = "*****",
        FirstName = "Test",
        LastName = "User",
        PrimaryEmail = "test@emailtest.com",
        UserAuthName = "testuser",
    })
}.Init())
{
    var response = appHost.ExecuteService(new MockSessionTest()) as AuthUserSession;

    response.UserAuthId   //= 1
    response.UserAuthName //= testuser"
    response.PrimaryEmail //= test@emailtest.com
}
```

Since it [just returns the Session that's registered in the Container](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/044156ad1b4bd2656704ed6dd003e284b83b3f14/src/ServiceStack/Service.cs#L110) when in `TestMode=true` I don't see where it could modify the `UserAuthId`.

Note `SessionAs<T>` is for resolving the concrete User Session type so you would typically use `SessionAs<AuthUserSession>()` or the Custom UserSession registered when you register the AuthFeature, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(), 
    new IAuthProvider { ... }));
```

Also checkout [MockSessionTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/MockSessionTests.cs) for different ways you can Mock a Session.